# Speeding up a custom built PC

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, gpu

I built my computer about a year and a half ago or so, and have noticed that even from the start it seemed a little sluggish. But I digressed and continued on without any other thought. Today I just used `UserBenchmark` to run benchmarking on the hardware that I have installed and the results that I got back were less than stellar.

My CPU benchmark was at `17.9%` while my Graphics card benchmark was at `33.7%` when compared with the average of users with those same hardware.

I am always good with your typical pc cleanup stuff, and I am running fairly lightly. Which leads me to believe, is it possible that I seated my CPU incorrectly when installing?

Here is my benchmark - http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/1545738

Can someone help me make the next move? Like its great that I can see my CPU is functioning abysmally, but what could my next steps be to try and speed this up?

---

Here is what the test showed for my CPU (Intel i5-4690k) and GPU (AMD R9 380)

[image]

The other components of my build are -

- Crucial BX100 250GB SSD
- WD Black 1TB
- Crucual BLS8G3D1609DS1S00 2x8GB - so 16GB DDR3 clocked @ 1600 MHz

My Hardware Specs are as follows -

- Intel Core i5-4690K

  - Bus Speed - 100 MHz
  - Core Speed - 800 MHz
  - Core Temp - 38.0 deg C
  - Power ~10 W
- AMD R9 380

  - Core Speed - 300 MHz
  - Memory Speed - 700 MHz
  - Core Temp - 57.0 deg C
- Motherboard - MSI Z97 PC Mate(MS-7850)

Comment: You should list the components of your computer. Specifics will help you get an answer. Also, it's not very likely that you seated the CPU wrong, the computer wouldn't run at all if it was wrong.

Comment: @TimmyJim thanks! added the build components. If you guys need anymore info just let me know, would like to try and figure out why my computer is considered a `"Surf Board"`

Comment: Go to the power options control panel (http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37376/~/windows-10%3A-change-power-management-settings) and make sure you are **not** set to "Power Saver". Set it to either "Balanced" or "High Performance". If it's not that then you need to go into your BIOS and make sure your CPU clock is set to the right value.

Comment: My first thought was: *SSD or more memory*, but i see you already have an SSD and 16GB of RAM. If it's really noticably slow, i would look to anti-virus software. Anti-virus software is the bane of modern computers. Try disabling or uninstalling anything (besides Windows Defender)

Comment: The BX100 is not nessecary faster than rotating rust (I got the BX200 which has the same disadvantage. Cheap. Silent, bit not fast. That does not explain the CPU benchmark though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the power profile is not on powersaver. Also, under Advanced Power Settings, make sure the max cpu state is at 100. 
If those are already set right, you should check the BIOS and make sure the multiplier is set for 35 (100 * 35 =3.5GHz).

Finally, some motherboards (like the MSI M5) have a hardware switch which limits the CPU performance. Since you didn't list the motherboard, I cannot say if you have one or not. Check your motherboards guide to see if it has one, and where it is located.

Sources: 
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2516827/intel-4690k-800mhz.html

Comment: I think this may have done it, I posted my motherboard (MSI Z97 PC Mate(MS-7850)) doing a restart now to check the bios etc.

Comment: You were spot on with the power profile, max was set at 5%, and the multiplier was ok. But my GPU is still sluggish, any suggestions for that?

Comment: It looks like it is underclocked either because of thermal throttling or a bad setting in the AMD Crimson Driver. I recommend going to the driver software and hitting "Reset". You can find the overclock settings under Gaming > Profile OverDrive.

Comment: Just reset everything, didn't seem to do anything for my GPU

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your CPU is thermal throttling. How are you cooling it? There isn't really enough information to go off here to help you out.

Your GPU seems to be the same. Could you post the temperatures of your components? What speed is your GPU and CPU running at? There are a lot of contributing factors that could affect this

Comment: Added core speed and temps to the question

Comment: I think we found your problem, your cores are underclocked for whatever reason. You will need to change your CPU multiplier up to stock at the very least, personally, I'd change your CPU core multiplier to 40 and get 4GHz on that core, and I would change your GPU to 950MHz or there abouts, whatever is stable.

It's very unusual that everything is underclocked like that